# Python Extension Can't Use library_dirs

Tags: python, c, libraries, python-extensions

WHen specifying library_dirs in a Python distutils.core.Extension I get this error when trying to build:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py:263: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'library_dirs'
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

Why is this? I am using Python 2.5 on Mac OS X.

Comment: As per the doc links, this is available for 2.5. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/dist/describing-extensions.html#SECTION002340000000000000000

Comment: Can you post your py file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you're not passing `library_dirs` to `distutils.core.Extension`, but to the `distutils.core.setup` function.